# Does the expansion pass also affect the main game?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-isle-of-armor, pokemon-crown-tundra

Aside from gaining access to the new regions (and the new pokemon within), does the expansion pass for Pokemon Sword/Shield affect the *main game* in any other way?

In some other games I know, having a certain DLC installed also altered some of the things in the base game (e.g. the Trespasser DLC changing some items you get as quest rewards in the Dragon Age Inquisition base game), even when you hadn't accessed the DLC area/story/... itself yet.

As long as you're not accessing the new areas, does it make a difference whether the expansion pass is installed or not? Meaning is there a benefit to starting the game with the expansion pass installed as opposed to purchasing and installing it after playing the base game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, no.

Patches released in conjunction with the launch of *The Isle of Armor* and *The Crown Tundra* allow players to access all new and returning Pokémon even if they have not purchased the Expansion Passes. This includes all Gigantamax forms and new moves.

New items are only available in the new areas, such as Apricorns and [Galarica Twig](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Galarica_Twig), so you can't find them in main game areas.

New clothes are also [exclusive of DLCs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLReCEZVy2o).